# Overriding an operator to use the derived class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, overriding, subtyping

I'm trying to override a virtual comparison operator in a sub-class, but I'm getting a compiler-error saying the derived class doesn't implement the base class' virtual operator.

I have a feeling it's to do with the fact that my derived operator doesn't use the base class' argument type.

A simplified version goes as follows:

```
struct Base {
  virtual bool operator ==(const Base) const;
};

struct Derived : Base {
  bool operator ==(const Derived) const {
    // implementation goes here
  }
};
```

Is there a way for me to do this, or do I have to do a type check in the `Derived` implementation to see if it's the right type?

Comment: Virtual comparison gives you run time type checking, do you want that?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I suppose I do, I'm gonna have a vector full of different derived classes, so without knowing which are which, I'd like to get the operator working on two classes of the same derived type

Comment: voted to close as **lacking reproducible example**

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm not sure how the example I gave is insufficient. It illustrates exactly what I want to do

Comment: And if you pass a reference as param?

Comment: uhm, virtual comparison or assignment is an anti-pattern. heterogenous vector, that's also an anti-pattern. but that's only two, why not add more?

Comment: It's hardly heterogeneous, it's homogeneous on the super-type, which is exactly the point.

Comment: just make the operator in base pure virtual function then you can do it: `virtual bool operator ==(const Base) const = 0;`

Comment: @Raindrop7 what does the `= 0;` do?

Comment: making the function pure thus the class abstract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a feeling it's to do with the fact that my derived operator
>   doesn't use the base class' argument type.

Exactly so.  The base class must take a const *reference* (so that it can have dynamic type `Derived`, and then you declare the override as:

```
bool operator ==(const Base& rhs) const {
    const auto pRhs = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&rhs);
    if (pRhs == nullptr)
    {
        return false;  // Not a derived.  Cannot be equal.
    }
    // Derived/Derived implementation goes here
}
```

Beware though:  A virtual comparison operator like this is very easy to get wrong.  You need a good motivating example to do it like this.  In particular, if you write:

```
Derived d;
Base b;
if (d == b)  // All is well - derived override called, and returns false.

if (b == d) // Uh-oh!  This will call the *base* version.  Is that what you want?
```

Also:

```
Derived d;
DerivedDerived dd;

if (d == dd) // Did you want to use the DerivedDerived comparison?
```

Comment: So, what if the right hand side is more derived than `Derived`? In other words, this code dispatches only on the left hand side in a comparison expression.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : Bad stuff - that's an excellent example!

Comment: By all means, @Electric Coffee, every single time you declare a member function that overrides a virtual function in its parent class, use 'override'!

Comment: @DonghuiZhang the override keyword was introduced in C++11, I'm working in C++98, not by choice mind you

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: About the best you can do to sort of emulate `override` in C++98 is to put `(void) sizeof( Base::foo( args ) )` in the body of the override. It checks for existence, but not virtuality, of a base class version.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ... and it doesn't catch my favourite error: Forgetting the "const" at the end of the "overriding" function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to type check in the Derived implementation that the parameter has the expected type.

For operators, you may prefer to define a virtual standard method and then to implement your operators by calling this method. This avoids to have unexpected or too large signatures for the operators.

```
struct Base {
  virtual int compare(const Base& source) const { return 0; }

  bool operator ==(const Base& source) const
    { return compare(source) == 0; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  int compare(const Base& asource) const override
    { const Derived* source = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&asource);
      int result = -2;
      if (source) { ... result = ...; }
      return result;
    }

  // redefinition to force the expected/right signature at this level
  bool operator==(const Derived& source) const
    { return compare(source) == 0; }
};
```

Comment: Why dispatch only on the type of left hand argument?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I agree: if you have 2 derived classes and if you want to make them comparable, you need to find a consistent way to disambiguate both types - multimethods is more general.